# What is a .framework file and how can I get it?

Tags: xcode, opencv

I'm attempting to use OpenCV in Xcode. I've installed OpenCV 2.4.12 using Homebrew. The associated files are located in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv`.

In the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/hello/hello.html) I am instructed to add "opencv2.framework" to my project as a binary library. There is no `opencv2.framework` file anywhere in my `opencv` directory.

Do I have to make the `.framework` file or something?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html

Answer (score 1):

Explore `/System/Library/Frameworks` for examples on your OS X system. These are bundles containing headers and the compiled framework binaries. If you don't have a .framework directory in the OpenCV resources that you installed, perhaps you installed the source code and you have to build the framework.